# How to redirect error from terminal to clipboard?

Tags: error-handling, terminal, clipboard

I am tired of rewriting errors from terminal to browser. Is there a way to redirect the error from the terminal to the clipboard. I have tried something like.

```
source venv/bin/activate | xclip -sel cli
```

This works for simple output from the command like ls, but it doesn't redirect errors.
This what also worked was.

```
source venv/bin/activate 2> error.txt
```

but how to redirect this direct to the clipboard?
2|?

Comment: http://alekdavis.blogspot.com/2017/10/save-stdoutstderr-to-clipboard-and-more.html might help

Comment: Do you want to capture stdout *and* stderr, or *only* stderr?

Comment: I want to capture stderr.

Comment: jdabtie exacly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect STDOUT to clipboard:

```
command | clip
```

Redirect STDERR to clipboard:

```
command 2>&1 | clip
```

Comment: This captures both stdout and stderr, hence my question.